# How to get list of HTTP response headers currently set in Node/Express?

Tags: node.js, express, http-headers

As I understand, when you are building a http response in node/express or whatever, the process consists of primarily two non-sequential steps: defining Headers and constructing the body. Headers include Set-Cookie headers.  In Express, the following methods are available with the response object for setting headers:

```
res.append(); // To append/create headers
res.cookie(); // A convenience method to append set-cookie headers.
```

As headers are only buffered and not actually sent until the response is sent, is there any method or mechanism to get the current list of headers set, along with their values, something like:

```
 headers = res.getHeaders(); //Returns an object with headers and values
 headers = res.getHeaders('Set-Cookie'); // To get only select headers
```

Answer (score 8):

try

```
console.log("res._headers >>>>>>>" + JSON.stringify(res._headers));
```

Comment: Works with NodeJS v6.9.2 32-bit. Please note this is not a public API. Anything you write that depends on this should have an automated unit test.

Comment: [This is deprecated](https://github.com/villadora/express-http-proxy/issues/413). Check out the solution below.

Answer (score 2):

I've managed to inspect what is being sent (including cookies) using `response.getHeaders()` [(available since Node 7.7.0)](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_getheaders) in combination with `on-headers`'s [module](https://github.com/jshttp/on-headers). Something like this:

```
import express from 'express'
import onHeaders from 'on-headers'

const router = express.Router()

function responseDebugger() {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(this.getHeaders()))
}

router.post('/', (req, res, next) => {
  onHeaders(res, responseDebugger)

  res.json({})
})

export default router
```

Comment: ^ this helped after hours of struggling to read cookies from the response object ^